# Open Angular Universal app by link without port

Tags: node.js, angular, apache, angular-universal

I’ve built an Angular Universal application, how to start it via a direct link, for example site.com, it only starts now if I add the site.com:4000 port to the address, what needs to be done or how to configure it to open without a port

thanks

Comment: you can do using ng-build. host as static website in server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the port from 4000 to 80.
By default site.com mean site.com:80.